# Ordenar por precio valor float python Json APi

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy utilizando unas api con Python. Al momento de bajar la data, baja desordenada, necesito ordenar por el mayor valor. No se si me explico, deseo ordenar el mayor precio de primero.

```
for data in responseData:
    data = [
        {   "username": data['created_by']['username'],
            "headline": data['headline'],
            "price_formula_value": data['price_formula_value'],
            "min_trade_size": data['min_trade_size']
        }
    ]

    xprecio=sorted(data, key=lambda price_formula_value: data[0]['price_formula_value'], reverse=True)
```

la informacion se muestra asi!

667196.5
566543.8002205938
639861.2331903176
566543.8002205938
466565.4825346066
639861.2331903176
670000.99
665000.99
599869.9061159228
653191.6755484493

Este es mi código, pero no me funciona, igual esta desordenada.

Comment: En la lambda deberías usar `price_formula_value` en vez de `data`

Comment: Buenas tardes , gracias por su comentario. Exacto asi esta!